# Nested datagrid column visibility based on the contents of its inner datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a nested datagrid and I want to hide outer datagrid column when the inner datagrid doesn't have any data. I am using MVVM pattern. Model fills the data in the collections which is binded to the view.

[Filled Datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV2w4.jpg)

The list of Component1, 2 and 3 are displayed through a datagrid inside the outer datagrid. Each label family will have two collections left and right.

When the Model doesn't have any components for left label collection, then I want the Left column to be hidden completely. As in below image. Similarly for Right column.

[Left Column Hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sh3I.jpg)

Please help me in achieving this.

I searched for similar situations on this site and google, but couldn't find anything similar to this.

Here is the XAML code:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Labels}"                          
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          CanUserDeleteRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="10*" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelFamily}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Right" Width="25*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding LeftLabel.Components}"                                              
                              CanUserAddRows="False" 
                              CanUserDeleteRows="False">                                        
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Left" Width="25*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RightLabel.Components}"                           
                              CanUserAddRows="False" 
                              CanUserDeleteRows="False">                        
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I am not posting the model code to keep the post short as much as possible.

Comment: Is this possible to solve this problem? Or I am trying something wrong and need some changes or use some other control?

Answer (score 0):

You can create converter like this (I used ObservableCollection for testing, you should use your container):

```
public class NoElementVisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        ObservableCollection<int> ienum = value as ObservableCollection<int>;
        return ienum == null || ienum.Count() == 0 ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (_converter == null)
            _converter = new NoElementVisibilityConverter();
        return _converter;
    }

    private static NoElementVisibilityConverter _converter = null;
}
```

And use it on your column like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Left" Width="25*"
                        Visibility={Binding RightLabel.Components, Converter={local:NoElementVisibilityConverter}>
```

Don't forget to include Converter namespace in your Window.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try and update over this.